# How to send comma separated values to via write/flush?

Tags: python, sockets, csv, python-3.4

I am trying to answer some questions of the server programmatically. 
For example, server asks `age, sex, location`.

I should answer it like `25,m,moon`. I can do it manually, but when I try to do it by a program I fail.

```
file.write("%s\n"%val)
file.flush()
```

where

```
val = "25,m,moon"
```

also tried

```
val = "25\,m \,moon"
```

server responded with

> Send them in a comma-separated list

Since, server accepts manual commas and wants comma separated values,
how can I perform it?

Comment: _How_ are you doing it manually?

Comment: I am working on an ubuntu machine. Manually means command line.

Comment: Right, but is it TCP or UDP? Are you using telnet, nc, or something else?

Comment: I am using TCP socket in my program. On terminal, I am using netcat(nc).

Comment: try, `val = "25 m moon"` and then `file.write(val.split())` and then `file.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

The server may be expecting a line ending. Try

```
val = "25,m,moon\r"
```

or

```
val = "25,m,moon\n"
```

or

```
val = "25,m,moon\r\n"
```

Comment: I tried these. However, server sends me an the same error. How can I send a comma separated list?